# Bind a c++ variadic templated member function to python using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, variadic-templates, pybind11

Recently I'm working on binding a header file written in c++ to python using pybind11, I have a problem when I need to bind a class looks like:

```
class animal{
public:
/* some code */
      template<typename... Args>
      void operator()(const Args&... args){
             /* implementation */
      }
}
```

I understand pybind11 can only wrap instantiated templated classes and functions, how can I wrap the variadic templated function and make it easy to instantiate?

Comment: What do you want the corresponding python method to look like? If it's `animal.__call__(self, *args)` then pybind11 does [support this](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/functions.html#accepting-args-and-kwargs), but how you reconcile the runtime-variadic method in python to the compile-time variadic template depends a lot on the implementation. Or alternatively you can decide on a maximum allowable number of arguments, and supply explicit wrappers for each with `pybind11::overload_cast`.

Comment: Thanks, I've consider these two solutions and wonder is there any better solution exist. I finally choose the latter as my implementation : ). Can you make your comment as a answer then I could select yours.